# Add/Update IEnumerable List

Tags: c#, linq, enums, ienumerable

I just want to ask how can I pass/update an IEnumerable List that will be used to show in dropdown cause I am missing a set of lines to add it and update `enumlist` so that I can only get the Text and Value that is `Arrived` and `Completed`. Here is my Enumerable list in my Model

```
    public enum DeliveryPermitStatus
    {

        Arrived = 1,
        Approved = 2,
        Cancelled = 3,
        Completed = 4,
        Submitted = 5
    }
```

Code in my Controller so I can add the filtered `enumlist` and I am missing code to viewbag the updated `enumlist` that will be used to show in dropdown

```
var enumlist = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DeliveryPermitStatus)).Cast<DeliveryPermitStatus>().Select(v => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = v.ToString(),
                    Value = ((int)v).ToString()
                });

                if (User.IsInRole(StaticRoleNames.Admin)) //your condition here
                {
                    foreach(var item in enumlist)
                    {
                        if(item.Text == "Arrived" || item.Text == "Completed")
                        {
                           //Missing Code Here

                        }
                    }

                }

                ViewBag.enumlist = enumlist;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are asking/wanting to do is edit the `ViewBag.enumlist` to be a reduced set of values based on a user's role? If so, then you could filter and assign the list inside your if statement and forego the foreach loop:

```
var enumlist = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DeliveryPermitStatus)).Cast<DeliveryPermitStatus>().Select(v => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = v.ToString(),
                Value = ((int)v).ToString()
            });

            if (User.IsInRole(StaticRoleNames.Admin)) //your condition here
            {
                ViewBag.enumlist = enumlist.Where(t =>  t.Text == "Arrived" || t.Text == "Completed");
            }
```

OR, if you need to keep the foreach loop, then you'll need to create a separate list to keep track of the "available values" for the enum list:

```
var enumlist = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DeliveryPermitStatus)).Cast<DeliveryPermitStatus>().Select(v => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = v.ToString(),
                Value = ((int)v).ToString()
            });

            List<SelectListItem> availableOptions = new List<SelectListItem>();

            if (User.IsInRole(StaticRoleNames.Admin)) //your condition here
            {
                foreach(var item in enumlist)
                {
                    if(item.Text == "Arrived" || item.Text == "Completed")
                    {
                       availableOptions.Add(item);
                    }
                }

            }

            ViewBag.enumlist = availableOptions;
```

Comment: Looks like plausible option +1, otherwise requirements are not very clear from the question itself

Comment: This is definitely what I am looking for! Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

You can't add elements to an IEnumerable, but you can easily get a List from it.
Just call ToList() before assign to your var enumlist.

Now you can add elements to it (be careful, don't add elements while enumerating it)